# Spring Boot + Mongodb : File Upload RESTFUL Web Service

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gridfs

I am creating a POC for uploading any document in the MongoDb Database using Spring Boot(MVC) RESTFUL Web service. It is working fine if we pass only String or any other basic datatype. And it recognizes local files in my system only when I tried to upload.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload/file", method=RequestMapping.post)
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("fileName", required=false) String fileName){
    logger.info("initialization of object");
    //----------------------------------------

     System.out.Println("name of File : " + fileName);  

    //----------------------------------------
}
```

This works fine. But if I want to pass byte stream or File Object to function. How can I write this function having these parameters? And upload those file contents in mongoDb.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload/file", method=RequestMapping.post)
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file", required=false) byte [] fileName){
     //---------------------
     // 
}
```

Please let me know the valuable suggestions for the same. Thank you.

Comment: InputStream input ??:>

Answer (score 0):

Just get request

```
@RequestMapping //whatever
public void yourEndpointMethod(ServletRequest req){
   req.getInputStream();//here
}
```